# Include condition for names containing apostrophes

Tags: sql, salesforce

I have been asked to edit this query to include a condition for surnames like `O'Brien` in Salesforce.

I have found that I need to add `%27` but I'm not sure if I have added it in correctly.

```sql
SELECT 
     o.id
    ,Member_RecordHidden__r.Member_ID__c
    ,Member_RecordHidden__r.FirstName
    ,Member_RecordHidden__r.LastName
    ,Member_RecordHidden__r.Date_of_birth__c
    ,Member_RecordHidden__r.Gender__c
    ,Member_RecordHidden__r.Member_Status__c
    ,Team_Name__c, Team__c
    ,Last_Visit_Date__c
    ,Status__c
FROM Opportunity o
WHERE 
    Team__r.Comp_id__c='1234' 
    AND Member_RecordHidden__r.Member_Status__c IN ('Active Member') 
    AND Status__c  IN ('Active') 
    AND Member_RecordHidden__r.LastName LIKE 'Test%' 
        OR  Member_RecordHidden__r.LastName LIKE '"'"%27'
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should just escape it with slash? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_quotedstringescapes.htm

It's contacts, right? This should get you started

```
SELECT Id, LastName
FROM Contact
WHERE LastName LIKE '%\'%'
LIMIT 10
```

[image]